# What is the universal formal deformation of a supersingular elliptic curve?

Tags: definition, elliptic-curves, deformation-theory

In Katz and Mazur's book "Arithmetic moduli of elliptic curves" (available [here](http://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/AWS/Files/KatzMazurArithmeticModuli.pdf)), the previously undefined notion of "universal formal deformation" is stated and I fail to understand how it is defined (actually, what it even *is*). The first occurence of it is on page 130 (page 71 in the pdf). More precisely, here is the statement.

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$, $E_0/k$ a supersingular elliptic curve, and $\mathbb{E}/W(k)[[T]]$ its universal formal deformation.

My question is: how is the object $\mathbb{E}/W(k)[[T]]$ defined? In particular, what is $W$?

If anybody could provide a definition for it or a reference, I would be really thankful.

NB: If this is any relevant, a supersingular elliptic curve was previously defined as those elliptic curves whose $p$-divisible group is, up to $k$-isomorphism, the unique $1$-parameter formal Lie group over $k$ of height $2$.

Comment: I presume $W(k)$ is the ring of Witt vectors over $k$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I see, thank you very much. I actually never heard of them before. Then, I assume that $\mathbb{E}/W(k)[[T]]$ is obtained by base change from $E_0/k$. Would you (or anybody reading this) know a reference as for the applications of this construction in the context of elliptic curves? Namely, what is meant by "formal deformation", what information this elliptic curve encodes, and so on...